# Cannot run php script with the good configuration on Mac OS Lion

Tags: php, macos, apache

I have a problem that is driving me crazy.I just want to execute a simple php script on my macbook pro with the native apache of mac OS.

I did all the step of configurations succesfully:
-Activate the web sharing
-Uncomment LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
-Uncomment Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
-Restart apache in the terminal with:sudo apachectl restart
-I put the php script in the folder Site

The script is just:

```
<?php
echo "Hello";
?>
```

When I try to launch it in the url with:http://localhost/~user/connect.php I always see the code over and not Hello.
I don't see what I did wrong and I can't find the solution on the Web

Thank you for your answers.

Quentin

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you mark files ending in .php to be excecuted as a script, you can do that with a *.htaccess*

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Comment: I did it and nothing change :-[

Comment: Did you name the file ".htaccess" and put it in the same folder as the php file? That's so weird...

Comment: Yes, I did it exactly the way you said me.